# Can we say that: $f(\beta)=\alpha$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space and  $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be an affine, sequentially continuous function.

Let $\{x_n\}\subset X $ be a sequence such that:
$$
\lim_{k}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k}{x_{n}}\underset{k}{\to}\beta\qquad~and~\qquad\lim_{k}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k}{f\big(x_{n}\big)}=\alpha
$$

Can we say that: $f(\beta)=\alpha$?

Comment: Ummm.... what does $\lim\limits_k$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is assumed to be affine. Thus $f=A+\gamma$ where $A$ is linear and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$. So $f\left(\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right)=\frac1k \sum_{i=1}^k A(x_i)+\gamma=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k\left(A(x_i)+\gamma\right)=
 \frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i) $. This implies the assertion since $f$ is sequentially continuous.